# Error when Querying DynamoDB GSI Using C# .NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb

**I am getting the following error for the code below:**

***Error    CS1061  'AsyncSearch' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'AsyncSearch' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?***

```
DynamoDBContext context = new DynamoDBContext(client);

                DynamoDBOperationConfig indexHashRangeOpConfig = new DynamoDBOperationConfig()
                {
                    IndexName = "ProjectFGDIndex",
                    ConsistentRead = false,
                };

                IEnumerable<Dashboardreq> list = await
                context.QueryAsync<Dashboardreq>(req.ProjectName, QueryOperator.Between, new string[] {
                                                 req.FileGeneratedFromDate+" " + Constants.DayBeginTime,
                                                 req.FileGeneratedToDate+" " + Constants.DayEndTime
                                                 });
```

**The error occurs in the await context.QueryAsync call.
Looking for guidance...**

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue ny making the following changes to the code:

```
List<Dashboardreq> list =
                await context.QueryAsync<Dashboardreq>(req.ProjectName, QueryOperator.Between, new string[] {
                                                 req.FileGeneratedFromDate+" " + Constants.DayBeginTime,
                                                 req.FileGeneratedToDate+" " + Constants.DayEndTime
                                                 }, indexHashRangeOpConfig).GetRemainingAsync();
```